# Query to WP db not working on regular PHP page

Tags: php, wordpress

Wonder if anyone has any thoughts on this, I'm putting a Wordpress theme toegther - As it's very custom requirements and I'm using a gallery fro one part I put together from a combination of other scripts (jcarousel etc) which does the job. This all works fine and dandy however I would like to query some of the tables in the WP database to feed the gallery.

I have used

```
$wpdb->get_results
```

To great effect on another page - however this is a template page type.

When I try and use `$wpdb->get_results` on my regular non template php pages it doesn't really play.

Do I need to add something into my custom pages to make it work, or do I have to make my custom PHP stuff into a plugin to utilise WP functions etc ?

Cheers

Comment: It would be more helpful if you quoted an error message rather than just saying "it doesn't really play"  :)

Comment: Do you have "global $wpdb;" before you tried to use get_results? More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jamesz brings up a great point. Make sure you have the $wpdb global. Also you may need to include the following files depending on where your php script is, if for example you don't have the usual wordpress header in your file...

```
This path assumes your php file is in the template dir, you may need to update the path to these files.

include_once('../../../wp-config.php');
include_once('../../../wp-load.php');
include_once('../../../wp-includes/wp-db.php');
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated - I'm looking at this now